# Correct or not? Writing file to a specific folder

Tags: python

I am trying to write the file to the folder New Innings 2 but instead it is getting written in New Innings. Pls help

```
import time
start_time = time.clock()
import numpy as np
Re=np.linspace(5,100,80)
print Re

import os
completeName = os.path.abspath("F:/New Innings/New Innings 2/R80000 .txt")
file = open("R80000 .txt", "w")
for j in np.arange(0,80):
    file.write((str(Re[j])+"\n")) 
    print((str(Re[j]))+"\n","\n") 
file.close()

print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

The original python file is saved in folder New Innings 2.

Comment: Does `F:/New Innings/New Innings 2` exist?

Answer (score 0):

You never use `completeName`. Replace the `open` statement as follows:

```
file = open(completeName, "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.abspath` does not change you to that directory. Instead, it will show you the full path of the file (that is, prepending `C:/My documents...` or similar where appropriate). You can see it printing `completeName`.

What you want is:

```
output_file = open("F:/New Innings/New Innings 2/R80000 .txt", "w")
# for loop
output_file.close()
```

Don't use `file` as a variable name, because it is a Python builtin.

But, even better, just use Numpy's [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
np.savetxt("F:/New Innings/New Innings 2/R80000 .txt", Re)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your current directory is `New Innings`, and `absdir` does not change your current dir.

What you need is:

```
mydir="F:/New Innings/New Innings 2"
if not os.path.exists(mydir):
    os.makedirs(mydir)
os.chdir(mydir)
# do your stuff ...
```